# How to return the top 3 spending customers per country?

Tags: sql, database, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.6, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to return the top 3 spending customers per country for a table like this:

| customer_id | country | spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | China | 45 |
| 152 | China | 8 |
| 159 | China | 21 |
| 160 | China | 6 |
| 161 | China | 9 |
| 162 | China | 93 |
| 152 | China | 3 |
| 168 | Germany | 91 |
| 169 | Germany | 101 |
| 170 | Germany | 38 |
| 171 | Germany | 17 |
| 154 | Germany | 11 |
| 154 | Germany | 50 |
| 167 | Germany | 63 |
| 168 | Germany | 1 |
| 153 | Japan | 7 |
| 163 | Japan | 58 |
| 164 | Japan | 44 |
| 153 | Japan | 19 |
| 164 | Japan | 10 |
| 165 | Japan | 15 |
| 166 | Japan | 24 |
| 153 | Japan | 105 |

I've tried the below code but it's not returning the correct results.

```
SELECT customer_id, country, spend FROM (SELECT customer_id, country, spend,
            @country_rank := IF(@current_country = country, @country_rank + 1, 1)
             AS country_rank,
            @current_country := country
       FROM table1
       ORDER BY country ASC, spend DESC) ranked_rows
       WHERE country_rank<=3;
```

Since some customers are also repeat customers, I want to make sure that it's the sum of spend per customer that's being taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using MySQL.  If you're running version 8 or later, then just use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY spend DESC) rn
    FROM table1
)

SELECT customer_id, country, spend
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

Comment: I am using SQL Fiddle which only goes up to MySQL 5.6

Comment: @gerg Then use DBFiddle, which supports MySQL 8: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Comment: thanks for the tip! The command seems to work except it is returning the same customer ID twice with different revenues for China instead of summing them into 1 and returning 3 unique customer IDs for the country. I am trying to work in a GROUP BY statement but don't think I'm putting it in the right place because it is returning an error.